# Installing Gurobi with python 3.6

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm using Windows and my default python version is:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Unfortunately, Gurobi is choosing 2.7 for installation.

How to install it with python 3.6?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you are trying to install `Gurobi` and what you mean by "Gurobi is choosing 2.7 for installation"?

Comment: Are you on Linux or Mac?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Answer (score 1):

You are in good shape because you have anaconda installed on windows.  If you follow the [instructions](https://www.gurobi.com/gurobi-and-anaconda-for-windows/) you will have gurobi installed with your version of python.  As of today, the instructions are

```
conda config --add channels http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi
conda install gurobi
```

If you still have trouble, read on.  From reading your question, it looks like you might also have gurobi installed separately but in your path.  This is probably OK as long as it is the same version of gurobi or if the anaconda distribution is ahead of the gurobi installation.  Also, if you used the setup.py or pip to try to install gurobi, you might run into trouble from [mixing pip and conda](https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-conda-and-pip/).  In the worst case, it might be easiest just to delete and reinstall conda.